# PHP Artisan terminal command error (Type Error)

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-artisan

I recently ran composer self-update and composer update, and I now face the following error when running "php artisan serve" in my command console. The same error happens with all commands, not just "php artisan serve".

Error:

[image: Error]

Line 217 in the directory mentioned in the error:

[image]

Let me know if you have any ideas about what I can do. This seems rather deep-rooted Laravel so I don't feel like messing with it.

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using? Which version did you update to?

Comment: 5.5.4 to 5.5.6 roughly 15 min ago through composer update. However I ran it again for the heck of it and saw it updating 5.5.6 => 5.5.7 so I guess it lacked the very latest updates. Technology's advancement speeds these days..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in the short moment between my last update from 5.5.4 to 5.5.6 (roughly 15 min ago) and posting this issue on Stack Overflow, I ran composer update yet again just for the heck of it and it updated to 5.5.7. Seemingly technology advances super fast! The error now has resolved itself with 5.5.7.

[image]

Comment: Well, looks like 5.5.6 had this bug when released and it has been fixed super quickly: https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases - By super quickly I mean within a minute. You had pretty bad luck :)